# Getting an element from ListView by index in Xamarin automated UI test

Tags: c#, listview, automation, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

[image]I have a `ListView` his automation Id = List
and I want to Tap on the second element.

How can I tap on him with his index?

```cs
app.tap((automationId)[1]) //?
```

Comment: Hey Nate! Are you using Xamarin Forms for developing the app? And have you tried to use REPL to get the tree? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-repl?tabs=vsmac Please paste an image of your tree, so we can help you better! :) . But it will be something like this app.TapAndWait(app.Query(q => q.Id(automationId).Child(1)).First().Label))

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: I posted an image of the tree

Comment: Hmm seems pretty complicated. Are you able to see the second element in the tree? Maybe you need to do a scroll down function and then do a tree again?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have assign AutomationId to first View in side DataTemplate. so I can tap on particular cell by index.

This will get all Cells inside ListView :

```
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("TeamListCell"));
```

You can tap on particular item by index like this :

```
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("TeamListCell").Index(0));
```

Comment: first one will tap the index 0 by default, not get all cells. 2nd one is working sometimes, sometimes not, i dont know why. In emulator is not working often but using real device always works